# fancybox calling when one of the radio values is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

how to call a fancybox when the one of the radio values is checked, html looks like;

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="A" />
<input type="radio" name="shipping" value="B" />
<input type="image" id="shipping" />
```

And I'm trying to load fancybox, but it calls allways on click in id="shipping" button, I need to call it when the shipping is B value only. Thanks

```
$("#shipping").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
});
```

I have tried to call `$.fancybox.close();` on `onComplete` option but it does not help

Comment: Are you saying you want the fancybox call at the moment the "B" radio is selected, i.e., as an immediate response to the user changing the radio button selection, or when the "shipping" image is clicked but only if "B" is the selected radio?

Comment: I want to show fancybox when the user click on #shipping button, but not allways, I need it when the shipping is on "B" value only.

Comment: I am assuming you are using fancybox v.1.3.4, aren't you? .... Additionally, what content fancybox should show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making fancybox to fire when selecting the radio button "B" only is the easy part, but there are other factors that you are not being clear about that would be needed to provide you with the right script: What type of content will (or where the content will come from) be shown in fancybox? ... and, will the form be submitted or used to fire fancybox only? (if you submit the form, fancybox will fired but it will close immediately since the page will be refreshed after submit), etc. etc.

Anyway, assuming that:

1. You are using fancybox v1.3.4 (hideOnContentClick is an option for fancybox v1.3.x only), and
2. Your form won't be submitted and the radio buttons will be used only to decide whether fancybox will be fired or not, then

Having this HTML:

```
<form id="testForm" method="post" action="">
    <label>A</label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="A" /><br />
    <label>B</label><input type="radio" name="shipping" value="B" /><br />
    <input type="image" id="shipping"/>
</form>
```

I would use this script:

```
$("#testForm").bind("submit", function(){
 var shipping = $(this).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
 if(shipping == "B") {
  $.fancybox({
   'content': '<span>you selected B</span>',
   'hideOnContentClick': false
  }); // fancybox
 } // if
 return false; // prevents the form to be submitted 
}); // bind
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the onStart option.  I've not tested the following...

```
$("#shipping").fancybox({
'hideOnContentClick': false,
    onStart: function(){
        var shipping = $('input[name="shipping"]:selected').val();
        if ( shipping != "B" ){
            $.fancybox.cancel();
        }
    }
});
```

You could probably improve this code a bit, and it may need some debugging.  If this doesn't work, try making a jsfiddle page that demonstrates your problem more completely. Then I can test/debug a solution.